# Solving a stiff nonlinear ODE system

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, constraint

The system I am trying to solve is simple, but looks pretty stiff and I have unsuccessfully tried to solve it with `StiffnessSwitching`. It is the following one:

```
x0=.001;
y0=10^64;
const=3*10^9;
h[a_] := Sqrt[y[a] + x[a]];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
system = {
           a*y'[a] + 3*y[a] == -const*y[a]/h[a],
           a*x'[a] + 4*x[a] == const*y[a]/h[a],
           x[1] == x0,
           y[1] == y0
         };

system2 = ReplacePart[system /. {x -> (F[#]^2 &), y -> (G[#]^2 &)}, {{3} -> F[1] == Sqrt[x0], {4} -> G[1] == Sqrt[y0]}];
{nds1, nds2} = NDSolveValue[system2, {F, G}, {a, 1, 10^7}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> 10^6, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
```

where `system2` has been defined to ensure the positiveness of the functions. But here I receive the stiffness message:

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At a == 1.`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

I have also tried with `ExplicitRungeKutta`, but nothing happened. It is clear that the initial condition `y0` is extremely high, but I need it. Trying with a lower `y0=10^16` it works, but only if I do not include `const`.

Any hint?

Comment: Evaluating `system2[[1;;2]]` at `a == 1` yields `{F'[1] -> 4.74342*10^42, 
 G'[1] -> -1.5*10^32}`.  Mathematica probably concludes that these enormous values indicate stiffness.  Try rescaling your variables to obtain smaller coefficients.  By the way, you do not need the code containing `Needs`.

Comment: Which coefficients are you referring to?

Comment: `y0` in particular.

Comment: Yes, with lower y0 it works, as I said. But, physically, I need that high value!

Comment: Try rescaling your variables so that these numbers are not so large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The computation can be performed as follows.  First, solve for `{x, y}` instead of `{F, G}`, because the ODEs are simpler, and then obtain `{F, G}` by taking the square roots of `{x, y}`.  Even then,

```
NDSolveValue[system, {x, y}, {a, 1, 10^7}]
```

immediately fails, claiming that the "step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected".  Perhaps, `NDSolve` concludes this, because the second equation in `system` is approximately `a*x'[a] + 4*x[a] == 3 10^41`.  Rescaling dependent variables to eliminate such large constants. i.e., `y` by `y0` and `x` by `const Sqrt[y0]`, probably would allow the computation to proceed.  In addition, changing the independent variable from `a` to `Log[a]` reduces the enormous domain of integration to a more manageable size.  As it turns out, this last transformation alone is sufficient to obtain the solution.  With `b == Log[a]`, `system` becomes

```
system1 = {y'[b] + 3*y[b] == -const*y[b]/h[b], x'[b] + 4*x[b] == const*y[b]/h[b], 
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0};
```

which is, incidentally, autonomous.  Then,

```
NDSolveValue[system1, {x[b], y[b]}, {b, 0, Log[10^7]}];
LogPlot[%, {b, 0, Log[10^7]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {b, "{x,y}"}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
Plot[First@%%, {b, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {b, x}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

[image]

The second plot, a blowup of `x` near the origin, shows that it grows rapidly but linearly there.  Why transforming only the independent variable is sufficient to obtain a solution is unclear.  Perhaps, `NDSolve` uses a different computational method for autonomous ODEs.

Comment: Great! Thank you! It was much easier than I had thought... last question: how do I use the solutions from NDSolveValue? I tried with `{xsol,ysol}=NDSolveValue[system1, {[b], y[b]}, {b, 0, Log[10^7]}];`, but when I evaluate one of them, for example, as `xsol[10]` it returns only `InterpolatingFunction[...][b][10]`. I would like to use those solutions to define other functions and so on... thank you!

Comment: Try `xsol /. b -> 10`.  Alternatively, start with `{xsol, ysol} = NDSolveValue[system1, {x, y}, {b, 0, Log[10^7]}];`  (Look at the output from `NDSolveValue` using `{x[b], y[b]}` vs `{x, y}` to see the difference.)